# Weblogic - Spring Injection can not find variable in the applicationContext

Tags: java, spring, web-services, weblogic, applicationcontext

I'm trying to deploy an application in weblogic 10gR3 but I'm having problems with beans initialitation if need a dymanic variable from the application context:

I need to put in the appication context some url to be used by webservices initialization, debbuging the code, I see that all the properties are contained in the context but when the webservice (bean) required the propertie an error is generated "....defined in null: Could not resolve placeholder...."

I don't know what to do, this is working on tomcat but I don't know what happend with weblogic.

Comment: Are you sure the properties file is placed in the scr\main\resources folder?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. During the application inilization, I see all the properties, but after the placeholder initialized the beans for web services create an error because they can't see a propertie in the context. Like I said before, this work on tomcat, I don't if weblogic has another way to load the properties or any limitation or special way :S